# Script to determine unused elements between XSLT and XML data source

Tags: xml, xslt

Given a somefile.xslt which calls a datafile.xml, does a script exist that would output a report of node sections in the datafile.xml that are not being called by somefile.xslt?

Obviously a visual inspection of each file could be used as the basis for the analysis, but I'm looking for an automated method.

For example, my xslt contains xpath like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//somenode/somesubnode/@attribute">
```

And the xml data source is expected to contain a **somenode/somesubnode** data structure. However, if it contains a **someothernode** data structure that's not a root element or child of an xpath called in the XSLT, it should be part of the "unused nodes" report.

Comment: How complex of an xslt are we talking about? What types of xpath expressions are you restricting yourself to? Do you allow for xslt parameters or xslt extension functions? xslt 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 using no extension functions

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a push approach (`xsl:apply-templates`) instead of a pull approach (`xsl:for-each`) you can have a template with a negative priority that "catches" any elements that don't get matched by another template. It's more of an "unmatched" check than an "unused" check though.

Basic example...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <foo>
        <bar>bar text</bar>
    </foo>
    <foo2>
        <bar>more bar text</bar>
    </foo2>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ident" priority="-1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc|foo|bar">
        <xsl:call-template name="ident"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="unused-element">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:processing-instruction>
        <xsl:call-template name="ident"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc>
   <foo>
      <bar>bar text</bar>
   </foo>
   <?unused-element foo2?><foo2>
      <bar>more bar text</bar>
   </foo2>
</doc>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Daniel. I'm finally getting back around to this project and checking this today. I'll let you know.

Comment: Daniel, trying to determine how to implementing your example in my debug strategy. Place this as a footer include into each xslt and format to a hidden div that I can turn on with DOM inspector?